# Using XFBML login button asks user to authenticate twice

Tags: facebook, xfbml

I am simply trying to setup Facebook Connect to allow the choice on my already established site to register with the registration form, or to register with Facebook Connect (this really should be easier than it is, the outdated docs are driving me insane).  When the user clicks the button, it opens the popup and asks to allow the things that I asked correctly.  However, when they click Allow, it asks to allow again (but just the basic profile info).  This is obviously triggered from the default action of clicking the fb:login-button, even though they have already logged in and allowed the app to access their data.

```
<fb:login-button size="medium" length="long" v="2" onclick="fb_login()"></fb:login-button>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/en_US/core.js"></script>
<script>
    FB.init({appId: '<app_id>', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});

    function fb_login() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.session) {
                if (response.perms) {
                    // they have allowed the app, continue with registration
                }
            }
        }, {perms:'email,user_birthday'});
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently you can just assign the permissions in the FBML and can bypass calling FB.login altogether.  It would would be great if Facebook would mention that in their docs (rant).

```
<fb:login-button size="medium" length="long" v="2" perms="email,user_birthday" onlogin="fb_login()"></fb:login-button>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/en_US/core.js"></script>
<script>
    FB.init({appId: '<app_id>', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});

    function fb_login() {
           // they have allowed the app, continue with registration
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I know this is not the normal protocol, but I just wanted to post a thank you. Working hard with code downloaded from facebook, I could not get extended permissions. 4 hours of google, manuals, and headaches got me no where. And you post above:
<fb:login-button size="medium" length="long" v="2" perms="email,user_birthday" onlogin="fb_login()"></fb:login-button>

That was what I needed!!!!! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that the problem is in assigning "onclick" event to `fb:login-button` that has its own default behavior already. Just ditch that login-button tag and create your own regular html button (link, image, or whatever you want) with that onclick event.

Comment: I would do that, but the button they have is exactly what I want and comes pre-built with translations.  I find it hard to believe that there isn't a way to do this without making my own button.